# Mongoose aggregation does not return the same results as other engine? Is there a syntax difference?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Playground with data sample: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OJKVFHLamig

Yet, when I run in mongoose within Node, the exact same collection and aggregation instead returns the total number of documents count and everything else is null:

`[ { _id: null, myCount: 130111, site: null } ]`

I've looked at all other variables, every comma in my production code and there's nothing else that explains this behaviour.

Is Mongoose unfit to use for the mongo aggregation framework or am I missing something about the syntax?

Schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { SiteModel } from './site.schema';

const JobModel = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String,
(other properties that are strings)
  title: String,
  site: { SiteModel },
});

export default mongoose.model('jobs', JobModel);


// SITE MODEL: 

export const SiteModel = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: String;
  title: String;
  city: String;
  UNID: String;

})
```

The models are incomplete as I'm only using it for reading purposes, the database is used by another app live and I'm merely building some reports/searching some data on it.

I am however pulling all the data that I need and It worked without a hiccup up until this.

EDIT 3: LOG ENTRY:

```
{ aggregate: "sites", pipeline: 
[ { $group: { _id: "$site.UNID", myCount: { $sum: 1 }, 
score: { $first: "$score" } } }, 
{ $limit: 20 }, 
{ $project: { site: "$_id", myCount: 1 } } ]
```

Comment: Could you show the schema as well

Comment: `db.setProfilingLevel(2)` and check the actual aggregation query that mongoose sends to the database.  I guess field names differ and 130111 is the total number of documents in the collection.

Comment: @AlexBlex set profiling level is not a function although .db is a property that has some stuff available. On what am I supposed to set profling level?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have added the schema to the post

Comment: on the db side https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/ Sorry I wasn't clear about it.

Comment: enable profiling, let mongoose to do aggregation, disable profiling, check queries in system.profile collection.

Comment: @AlexBlex The db is being used in production so I wouldn't want to do that BUT there is a full log already running and I managed to get the command from the log, I have edited my post and added there.

Comment: @AlexBlex I think it was a typo.... I worked at the aggregation config in isolation from the mongoose call to aggregate which... makes the aggregation on the 'sites' collection not the 'jobs' collection.... since jobs.site is site data, it still <kinda> worked.... 2 days, 14+ hours on this trying to figure out how aggregation works...

Comment: So it's working after fixing the typo?

Comment: @JohnnyHK it does work... at least I'll know to look in the log the next time and learnt a ton about aggregation... kinda wish I hadn't, at least not this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong mongoose model to run the aggregation on, but the collections were similar enough that it was still returning  results. I realized this by looking into the db logs and seeing exactly which collection my aggregation was running on.